# Is it possible to set a selection count limit on p:selectManyMenu in Primefaces?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a situation where I have a field that depending on the settings of other fields on the screen this field should allow unlimited selections, 3 selections, or one selection.

```xml
<p:selectManyMenu value="#{orderBean.selectedAddOns}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{catalogBean.addOns}"/>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

So there are 10 possible add-ons, but one of the options (a field not listed above) means that only one add-on is allowed.  Another one means that 3 are allowed and for any other option or no options at all, any or all add-ons can be selected.  So what would be the most straight forward way to dynamically limit how many selections can be made?  I'd like it so that when the limit is 3 and the user selects a 4th, it unselects the first one they had selected, that is, if they select B, C, D and then later select G, the selection becomes C, D, G if B was the first selection they made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in this way.

```xml
<p:selectManyMenu widgetVar="selectManyMenuWV" 
                  showCheckbox="true">  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 4" itemValue="4" />  
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

```javascript
<script>              
   $(function() {
      selectManyMenuWV.items.on('click', function() { 
         restrictMenu($(this).text())
      })
      selectManyMenuWV.checkboxes.on('click', function() {                                                       
         restrictMenu($(this).parent().parent().text())
      })
   });

   function restrictMenu(notValue) {
      //max selection size
      maxSelectionVar = 4;
      if (maxSelectionVar.length != 0) {
         if (selectManyMenuWV.input.find(':selected').length > maxSelectionVar) {
            selectManyMenuWV.unselectItem(selectManyMenuWV.items.filter(function() {    
            if(selectManyMenuWV.input.find(':selected').eq(0).text() != notValue)                                         
               return $(this).text() == selectManyMenuWV.input.find(':selected').eq(0).text();  
            else
              return $(this).text() == selectManyMenuWV.input.find(':selected:last').text();
             }))
          }
       }
    }
</script>
```

Note: this approach has it's cons:

- It unselectes based on the item's text.
- It is only client-side, that means if someone disabled/hacked the JS he would be able to select more values. I would also put a validation on the server-side.

A small working example can be found on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/selectManyMenu/main.xhtml). And an [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/selectManyMenu/main.xhtml).

Hope this helps.